# How to drill into a two dimensional array object using Form Group Tags in React JS and populate dropdowns dynamically?

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, array.prototype.map

```
<Form.Group controlId="phoneName">
  <Form.Label>Phone Names</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control
    as="select"
    name="phoneName"
    value={values.phoneName}
    onChange={handleChange}
    isInvalid={!!errors.phoneName && !!touched.phoneName}
  >
    {phones.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          {item.phoneName.map((phone, index) => {
            return <option key={index}>{phone.name}</option>;
          })}{" "}
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </Form.Control>
  <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
    {" "}
    {errors.phoneName}{" "}
  </Form.Control.Feedback>
</Form.Group>;
```

The **output** prints  then  then  tags, and dropdown is empty but can see result in inspect-->elements-->and in the html i selected the dropdown and saw the result, the values are coming from JSON which is in another branch of GitHub so i use API call to get data and it works fine,
so i use a dropdown first to get the item phone and after that i want to select from the dropdown called phoneName to get options like nokia, samsung etc. but only the tag thing doesn't print correct values in the form control

```
[
  {
    gadgets: "phone",
    phoneName: [
      { name: "nokia", phoneColor: "blue", memory: "enough" },
      { name: "samsung", phoneColor: "black", memory: "little" },
    ],
  },
  {
    gadgets: "ipad",
    phoneName: [
      { name: "apple", phoneColor: "white", memory: "high" },
      { name: "samsung-g", phoneColor: "black", memory: "low" },
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure as to what library you're using for your form and there's no clear example of what you're trying to achieve but the following might send you in the right direction.

Firstly, you're trying to render a div inside a select list. `Select` lists generally take `options`. Once again I'm not sure of the lib you're using so can't make an accurate assumption

Secondly you had an error in your code which I have fixed through editing your post. On line 2 you had typed `<Form.Label>Phone Names</<Form.Label>`. The closing tag is incorrect

My personal opinion is that your data is not labeled in the most optimized way. I would change `phoneName` to `gadgetList` since the array holds all the gadgets associated with the `gadget` property

For the results I think you're trying to achieve, you could try the following:

```
  {data.map((item,index) => {
        return (
          <div key={item + index}>
            <h4>{item.gadgets}</h4>
            <select>
              {item.phoneName.map((gadget) => (
                <option>{gadget.name}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

This would essentially map out 2 `divs` with 2 `select lists`. The select options would be the phone names.

An example can be seen here : https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-maxwell-tylpwd?file=/src/App.js

Hopefully this can help you. If not, please put your code into a sandbox so we can help assist you better in solving the problem :)

Comment: Thank you, for replying. So, I have a dropdown named Gadgets - there i am displaying phone and ipad. So, when i select phone in my second dropdown i only want to see names which are nokia and samsung. But, in the GUI no values are popping in the dropdown, so i try to inspect-->elements and see whats inside the dropdown and theres a tag <select name="PhoneName" id="phoneName" class....> and then below it i can see dropdown <select>....</select> and dropdown it contains <option>nokia</option>, <option>samsung</option>, value i see are correct but i can't see inside form. Added phoneform sandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-roentgen-6gjrmv?file=/src/PhonesForm.js

Comment: @AxitaPatel ah ok I understand what you're trying to achieve. Let me change my answer

Comment: Is this inline with what you're trying to accomplish ? https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-feather-hnh4sq?file=/src/App.js . It's just a matter of mapping through the correct index using .find() once you have selected a gadget

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-voice-9y5fqi?file=/src/PhonesForm.js

Comment: I have added changes to above link, the json that array objects is in a different directory and it's a json file. Second, the API call file is called Phone.js. Third, In the code you posted the values which are not dynamic, they come from initialValues= selectedGadget: "phone", selectedPhone: "".So, i am dynamically changing values.   When i first see the drop down i have a message like "select a phone" rather than manually adding first value as phone so i tried many things since yesterday and it didn't work so commenting again. In utilities file where i am using useEffect and props.

Comment: So If I understand correctly, The solution I provided is correct except for the fact that the first drop down list should say "select" and have dynamic gadgets?

Comment: Yes sir the solution was working and correct but i have dynamic values

Comment: Ok great, if you could give a larger example of the dynamic values, I can re work it as needed

Comment: Sure, so in the above codebox link it had a different directory phgadgets-sql which has json file. Then, in the src it had Phone.js file which contains the url that usefetch the contents of json file. The phonesform doesnt contain json and i removed also some other things i removed and i tried to change the .find with other things but no progress on that so kept it the way it was before

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-voice-9y5fqi?file=/src/PhonesForm.js